# How to change the wallet address using the monero-wallet-cli?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, address

I'd like to use a specified address using the `monero-wallet-cli` and not a new one it generates. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `monero-wallet-cli` operates on *wallets*, which contain private and public *keys*, which have *addresses*. Thus, to use the `monero-wallet-cli` with a different address (not generated by your wallet), you have to generate a *new* wallet using the keys for that address or from the seed words of the wallet that first created the address.

See `monero-wallet-cli --help`:

```
...
  --generate-from-view-key arg          Generate incoming-only wallet from view
                                        key
  --generate-from-spend-key arg         Generate deterministic wallet from 
                                        spend key
  --generate-from-keys arg              Generate wallet from private keys
                                        wallet keys
  --generate-from-json arg              Generate wallet from JSON format file
... or...
  --restore-deterministic-wallet        Recover wallet using Electrum-style 
                                        mnemonic seed
```

Once you've created a wallet for your address, you can then use it.

Comment: What about if I generate the new wallet and I just add my address instead of the one it generated? Like the GUI one where you have the possibility to change address if you want. How to do that using CLI?

Comment: You cannot add an address from another wallet. Even in the GUI. A wallet can have multiple accounts and address, which you can switch between, you just can't add an address created by a different wallet.

Comment: Oh, i thought i could since i have seen that in settings but tbh I haven't tried